# Select 'x' returns "x"()

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I want to return 3 columns, A(description), 'D'(hard coded value of D), Q(date)

```
=query('Detailed Plan'!$A$2:$Q, "select A,'D',Q where D = date)
```

It returns the following results.  Rows 2 and greater are exactly what I want and would be perfect if I didn't get the first row.  How do I get a hard coded value into a column without "D"() showing up in the first row?

```
blank, "D"(), blank
Description, D, date
Description, D, date
Description, D, date
```

Thanks so much for any help that is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'label' in the query string.

```
=query('Detailed Plan'!$A$2:$Q, "select A, D, Q where D = date label A 'Description', D 'Some value', Q 'Date' ", 0)
```

EDIT: if you don't need headers at all, try

```
=query('Detailed Plan'!$A$2:$Q, "select A, D, Q where D = date ", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  This solution did add titles to the columns but my hope is to remove the first row that includes the titles.  All I need is the data in row 2 and down.

Comment: If you don't want any headers see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That removed headers but I didn't notice the other change from your first response.  Select A, D instead of Select A, 'D'.  I need the letter D to show up in the second column.

Comment: oh, you want the letter D in every row of the table, right?

Comment: Then what it the where-part for in your formula?

Comment: Yes I do want the letter D in the second column.  The hope is to get data from column A, hard coded letter D, and data from column Q.